# custom event to check if the style image is missing in react native mapbox gl maps

Tags: react-native, mapbox, react-native-mapbox-gl

I am using [react-native-mapbox-gl/maps](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps) extensively in my react native app and I wanted to add dynamic style icons to the chart style.

The javascript mapbox library has a nice event called [styleimagemissing](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/) with which we can check which image for a style is missing and construct it.

Is there something similar in the react-native mapbox gl library?

In other words, I would line to achieve something [like this](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image-missing-generated/) using the react native mapbox-gl library.

Answer (score 0):

This is implemented in react native mapbox gl 8.0 and later. See [Images#onImageMissing](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/docs/Images.md)